# How can I only list emails that contain meeting invites with Outlook on the web?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I am cleaning my email inbox using [Outlook on the web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_on_the_web). I'd like to only list emails that contain meeting invites, so that I can see which ones to delete or archive. How can I only list emails that contain meeting invites from Outlook? I'm ok if it lists emails that contain meeting invites from other services.

Example of an email that contains a meeting invite (see red arrow):

[image]

I couldn't see such a filtering option in the search box. Is the filtering option somewhere else, or via some keywords?

Searching for `hasattachments:yes ext:ics` or `hasattachments:yes ext:ical` doesn't return meeting invites from Outlook that don't contain attachments. It does return meeting invites from Google Calendar, as those contain an "explicit" .ICS attachments (explicit from OWA standpoint, i.e. [they do show up as an attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNkaL.png), unlike for invite from Outlook, that do not show up as an attachment in OWA).

Comment: Do all other appointments than Outlook-originated include ICS, but Outlook has something else that is common that can be searched on?  Does owa support searching headers? Do Outlook invites have something specific in the header that's common?

Comment: @BlindSpots Good questions. I agree these are good research directions. I don't know the answers.

Comment: Poorly researched questions are not off topic. I believe the concensus is downvote, not close, for poorly researched questions.

Comment: @BlindSpots I'd like to list emails that contain meeting invites from Outlook. I'm ok if it also lists emails that contain meeting invites from other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reddit user [cyberzen7](https://www.reddit.com/user/cyberzen7) [pointed](https://redd.it/17ml2tm) me to the proper search query:

```
kind:meetings
```

It returns Outlook meeting invites as well as non-Outlook invites such as gCal (as long as they are recognized as meeting invites by Outlook, which is shown by a [calendar icon before the email subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzlbl.png)).

Comment: Does `messageclass:meeting` work as well?

Comment: @BlindSpots it seems to only list a small subset of Outlook meeting invites.

Comment: @BlindSpots I couldn't infer any pattern yet. That's strange, there must be some explanation

Comment: @BlindSpots [If I search for `messageclass:meeting` in my emails with Outlook on the web, what kind of search is it doing?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172719/18147)

Comment: @BlindSpots Where did you get that suggestion from? Not a single result on Google suggests that exists as a search operator (at least not by default).

Comment: Advanced Query Search (ASQ) for OWA is more limited than Desktop. New features are being added.  The suggestion was an abbreviated form of `messageclass:ipm.schedule.meeting` You could try that too but might have the same outcome.