# If I search for `messageclass:meeting` in my emails with Outlook on the web, what kind of search is it doing?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

On [How can I only list emails that contain meeting invites with Outlook on the web?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172691/18147), one suggestion was to search for `messageclass:meeting` in my emails with Outlook on the web. It does return some emails, but not necessarily meetings: it seems to return some emails based on the text the email contains.

However, what kind of search is it doing? Is it simply some string match and it, which string(s) is it matching (e.g., must an email contain `messageclass` and `meeting`?)? I couldn't finder a pattern yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, `messageclass:meeting` is broken down into 3 strings: `message`, `class` and `meeting`. An email must satisfy these 3 conditions:

- have 1 word that has `message` exactly or as a substring  (e.g., "message"),
- have 1 word that has `class` exactly or as a substring (e.g., "classifier"),
- have 1 word that has `meeting` exactly or as a substring (e.g., "meetings").

Similarly, `researchtalk:meeting` is broken down into 3 strings: `research`, `talk` and `meeting`.

However, `researchtalk` is not broken down into 2 strings: an email must contain the word "researchtalk" or have a word for which "researchtalk" is a substring. Same for `messageclass`.